# Control remote pi GPIO with domoticz

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, domoticz

There are 2 pi in this setup:
 - PI-domo: running domoticz
 - PI-pump: controlling a pump with one GPIO

Those pi are far away, but can communicate through network.  PI-domo has some passwordless ssh login setup to pi-pump, and contains three scripts:
- pump_on.sh: sends value to gpio with ssh to turn pump on and returns 1

```
  `ssh pi@pi-pump -n "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value" && echo 1`
```

- pump_off.sh: sends value to gpio with ssh to turn pump off and returns 0

  `ssh pi@pi-pump -n "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value" && echo 0`
- pump_status.sh: returns 1 if pump is on, 0 if pump is off.

All three scripts work as expected when launched in bash, but I can not find how to call them with domoticz.  I created a virtual switch and set those as script:///.....[on off].sh but domoticz doesn't seem to be running any of them.  nor could I find a place to read the status...

Any idea or link to a RECENT (working) tutorial would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: stupid me.
It turns out domoticz process was running as root and root didn't have the key setup for passwordless ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a old thread and it is answered already, but I have stumbled on the same issue and found that [online answers](https://www.domoticz.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6733) lacked detail. So, here it goes:

1. On PI-domo run
   `sudo su` to become root
2. Generate a new key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "nameofyourkey"`
3. Copy your key to PI-pump by using `ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/yourkey.pub pi@pi-pump`
4. ssh to pi-pump to test that ssh agent for root is working, and if all is well exit and go back to become a pi user.

Note 1: Although logging in as root of PI-domo, it is critical that pump_off and pump_status.sh contain pi@pi-pump and not root@pi-pump or this approach will fail.

Note 2: Domoticz log indicates that the above process has some error by outputting `Error: Error executing script command (/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/pump_off.sh). returned: 65280`. Note the 65280 error in particular